# Остаток от деления бинарных чисел java

Tags: java

Какой есть алгоритм нахождения остатка от деления двоичных чисел?нужно реализовать деление полиномов,представил их в виде `110010 mod 1010` а дальше ступор...

Comment: 110010 - это у вас строки?

Comment: Возможно, проще посчитать остаток до преобразования. А вообще, алгоритм стандартный, делите, как в школе уголком, независимо от системы счисления.

Comment: Алгоритм нахождения остатка от деления двоичных чисел ничем не отличается от алгоритма нахождения остатка от деления десятичных, восьмеричных и любых других -ичных чисел. Все числа одинаковые и от формата представления ничего не меняется.

Comment: ``int x=0b110010; int y=0b1010; int z; z = x %y;``

Comment: @vp_arth каждая цифра-i ый элемент массива

Comment: @Kirq посмотрите реализацию деления больших чисел  в исходниках java (класс BigDecimal метод divide)